# Can a Second-level domain be considered as a Fully-qualified domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, domain-name, fqdn

I often see people talking about *FQDNs* (fully-qualified domains) to describe subdomains (e.g., `networkengineering.stackexchange.com`) that are under a second-level domain (e.g., `stackexchange.com`). I wonder if a *SLD* can be considered a FQDN itself. For instance, in this case, `stackexchange.com` is already enough to bring us to the front page of Stack Exchange. Is there any conventional document/standard behind these terminologies?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Any domain is a subdomain and is an FQDN, it all depend on the context, you can not say anything just by looking at the string.

From [RFC 8499 DNS Terminology](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8499):

> Domain name:  An ordered list of one or more labels.

and

> Fully-Qualified Domain Name (FQDN):  This is often just a clear way
> of saying the same thing as "domain name of a node", as outlined
> above.  However, the term is ambiguous.  Strictly speaking, a
> fully-qualified domain name would include every label, including
> the zero-length label of the root: such a name would be written
> "www.example.net." (note the terminating dot).  But, because every
> name eventually shares the common root, names are often written
> relative to the root (such as "www.example.net") and are still
> called "fully qualified".

and

> Subdomain:  "A domain is a subdomain of another domain if it is
> contained within that domain.  This relationship can be tested by
> seeing if the subdomain's name ends with the containing domain's
> name."